# gulp webserverでのエラー

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

gulpコマンドを叩いた際、稀にこのエラーが出てserverが立ち上がりません。稀にと書いたのは一度睡眠してから朝起きてこのコマンドを叩いたりすると動くことがあるのです笑

gulp serveコマンドを押してもこのエラーが出るのでgulp-webserver周りのエラーだと思われます。
あとたまにこのように２行出るときもあります

```
... Uhoh. Got error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost ...
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

gulpfile.js内のserverタスクは以下のとおりです

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  gulp.src('app/')
     .pipe(webserver({
       livereload: true,
       directoryListening: true,
       open: true
     }));
});
```

原因がわからないので教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: [StackOverflowの方でも質問されている](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30233799)ようですが、もうそちらで解決されたのでしょうか？ （なお複数個所で同じ質問をされる場合は、その旨を書いていただけると助かります http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1770）

Comment: すいません、解決いたしました！

Comment: わかりました。こちらにもその解決策を回答として投稿していただけませんか？

Answer (score -1):

/private/etc/hostsに

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

を追加します

hostsファイルがなければ作成します